# Hierarchy For Users In SugarCRM CE?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Let's say there are some Users: user1,user2,user3,user4,user5 and user10.

user3 and user4 reports to user1,
user5 reports to user2.

If user3 creates some records that records can only visible for user3/user4 and user1,user10 not for 2 and 5.

If user2 creates records that records only visible for users 2,5, user10 not for 1,3,4.

One more thing, user10 let's say CEO or some kind of person, this user10 can see all records created by user1, user2, user3,user4 user5 and himself.

Can any one give me the procedure steps?

Regards,

Narendra

Comment: Pretty sure that's what the Reports To field is for. Managers get to see all of the records accessible to users "below" them. Works as long as you don't have multiple managers on the same tier. Otherwise, check out the https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am looking for alternative solution,  i heard that we can do this without using securitysuite if i am not wrong, but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: SecuritySuite is the only solution to do this for CE.